usetagform works inside equation but not work inside align
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{mytag}{\{}{\}}
\newcounter{mycn}
\newcommand*{\mysym}{\refstepcounter{mycn}\usetagform{mytag}\tag{\themycn}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation}
        a=b
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}
        c=d \mysym
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{align}
        a & b \\
        b & c
    \end{align}

    \begin{align}
        a & b \mysym \\
        b & c \mysym
    \end{align}
    
\end{document}



I'd do it differently, defining environments for the alternate tag form.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\newtagform{mytag}{\{}{\}}

\newcounter{savedequation}
\newcounter{myequation}
\newcommand{\premy}{%
  \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{myequation}}
  \usetagform{mytag}%
}
\newcommand{\postmy}{%  
  \setcounter{myequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{braceequation}{b}
 {%
  \premy\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}\postmy
 }{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{bracealign}{b}
 {%
  \premy\begin{align}#1\end{align}\postmy
 }{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[32][1-5]    
\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[33][1-5]
\begin{braceequation}
  c=d
\end{braceequation}
\lipsum[34][1-5]
\begin{align}
  a & b \\
  b & c
\end{align}
\lipsum[35][1-5]
\begin{bracealign}
  a & b \\
  b & c 
\end{bracealign}
\lipsum[36][1-5]
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\lipsum[37][1-5]

\end{document}


